# There's no app\start\global.php file in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was integrating BrainSocket with my laravel application. BrainSocket needs to add these two lines :

```
require app_path().'/filters.php';
require app_path().'/events.php';
```

in app/start/global.php. But i can't find the folder start in the app folder of my laravel application. How can i integrate brainsocket with my laravel 5 application?

Comment: In laravel 5 there is no global.php file. You have to  include in service ServiceProviders

Comment: why not use a namespace of filters.php and events.php, if they are class files

Comment: @vijay4vijju Can you provide a sample of it for integrating brainsocket?

Comment: @Nisthar are those files php class files?

Comment: its obvious that https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket is a Laravel 4 package and might not work properly in Laravel 5

Comment: @Digitlimit i think there's not much difference between laravel 4 and laravel 5. I found a way to do this here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/appstartglobalphp-file-location . But it didn't make any sense to me. If anyone could give a sample specific for integrating brainsocket, It would be easy to understand.

Comment: check my answer. I think it integrates `BrainSocket` events in Laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

To make some features BrainSocket work in  Laravel 4 you add the code below in `events.php`

```
Event::listen('generic.event',function($client_data){
    return BrainSocket::message('generic.event',array('message'=>'A message from a generic event fired in Laravel!'));
});

Event::listen('app.success',function($client_data){
    return BrainSocket::success(array('There was a Laravel App Success Event!'));
});

Event::listen('app.error',function($client_data){
    return BrainSocket::error(array('There was a Laravel App Error!'));
});
```

Since there is no `events.php` in Laravel 5, simply pop open `app\providers\EventServiceProvider.php` and modify it as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use BrainSocket;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        $events->listen('generic.event',function($client_data){
            return BrainSocket::message('generic.event',array('message'=>'A message from a generic event fired in Laravel!'));
        });

        $events->listen('app.success',function($client_data){
            return BrainSocket::success(array('There was a Laravel App Success Event!'));
        });

        $events->listen('app.error',function($client_data){
            return BrainSocket::error(array('There was a Laravel App Error!'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But where to add these lines require app_path().'/filters.php';
require app_path().'/events.php'; there's no app/start/global.php.

Comment: BrainSocket, https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket documentation did not provide any code to be placed in `filters.php` `app_path().'/filters.php';` core Laravel 4 file and does not belong to BrainSocket package. You can go ahead and test your application